# Get the real error messages from a Wordpress rest return

Tags: wordpress

How to get real error messages from Wordpress's return feedback.

Using try and catch just returns me the server error, for example the message below:

return this message complete:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

If I enter error.message, the error returns this:

```
Request failed with status code 403
```

And this is the message that comes back from rest, this on the Chrome tab Network:

```
code: "rest_cannot_create"
data: {status: 403}
    status: 403
message: "Sem permissão para criar posts com este usuário."
```

the function I'm using is this:

```
const onSubmit = async (event) => {
    try {
      const response = await EventsService.create(event);
      const { id } = response.data;
      console.log(id);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Grab the response, not the error

Comment: I got it here, I had to change the trycatch to then, I'll leave the question open, because someone may have this question too.